# Spring Integration - FolderClosedException

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to filter incoming mail messages - if the mail body contains, for example, 'github.com', the application will not reply automatically. So I tried writing an IntegrationFlow for that (please see code below). I am not sure how to handle it since it seems like the Transformer cannot open the inbox folder, which seems to be Java Mail API issue?

```
@Bean
open fun flow(): IntegrationFlow
{
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from("emailReceiveChannel")
        .transform(transformer())
        .filter("@messageFilter.containsDomainNames('payload')")
        .handle(MessageHandler(MailServiceImpl(javaMailSender(), mailStore())))
        .get()

}
```

where `transfomer()` is:

```
@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "emailReceiveChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
open fun transformer(): org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer
{
    return MailToStringTransformer()
}
```

and the `messageFilter`:

```
@Component
class MessageFilter
{

    @Filter
    open fun containsDomainNames(messageBody: String): Boolean
    {
        return messageBody.contains("github.com") ||
               messageBody.contains("trello.com") ||
               messageBody.contains("bitbucket.com")
    }
}
```

.

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(autoStartup = "true", value = "emailReceiveChannel", poller = (arrayOf(Poller(fixedDelay = "10000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "10"))))
open fun mailReceivingMessageSource(mailReceiver: ImapMailReceiver): MailReceivingMessageSource
{
    return MailReceivingMessageSource(mailReceiver)
}
@Bean
open fun pollingConsumer(): PollingConsumer
{
    return PollingConsumer(emailReceiveChannel(), MessageHandler(MailServiceImpl(javaMailSender(), mailStore())))
}

@Bean
open fun outputChannel(): PollableChannel
{
    return QueueChannel()
}

@Bean
open fun emailReceiveChannel(): PollableChannel
{
    return QueueChannel(10)
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
2018-01-20 13:05:53.840 ERROR 8204 --- [ask-scheduler-6] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform mail message; nested exception is javax.mail.FolderClosedException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage@3f0ef4a2, headers={id=e9eff05d-e9af-70e4-73f7-c4d39c740291, timestamp=1516449953838}]
at org.springframework.integration.mail.transformer.AbstractMailMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMailMessageTransformer.java:83)
at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:129)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:271)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:372)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:366)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:83)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Caused by: javax.mail.FolderClosedException
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getProtocol(IMAPMessage.java:153)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPBodyPart.loadHeaders(IMAPBodyPart.java:390)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPBodyPart.getNonMatchingHeaderLines(IMAPBodyPart.java:371)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1536)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:948)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:538)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.transformer.MailToStringTransformer.doTransform(MailToStringTransformer.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.transformer.AbstractMailMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMailMessageTransformer.java:80)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Looks like this is fully related to the bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4299. Try to use solution suggested there

Comment: @ArtemBilan not sure how to implement that solution in my case? Author of that ticket uses totally different, verbose approach, while I'm trying to let Spring filter my messages

Comment: Right, but folder is closed already and you have to reopen it and refetch message to proceed with transformation

Comment: Are you sure there is no other approach to filter mail messages basing on their content in Spring Integration?

Comment: Right, there is `mailFilterExpression`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mail.html#mail-filtering

Comment: I have read the docs and tried to set up something with expressions, but that didn't work well. Alright, I'll keep my eyes posted on that ticket and try other solutions. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 3):

This issue are corresponding with integration lib update, that is why downgrade of this lib is helpfull, but the right way is to add one more java mail property: simpleContent.

Please read docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/mail/AbstractMailReceiver.html#setSimpleContent-boolean-

Also my code snippet:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow userEmailFlow(EmailProperties props,
                                     EmailToUserTransformer emailToUserTransformer,
                                     UserMessageHandler userMessageHandler) {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(props.getImapUrl())
                          .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "false")
                                  .put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory")
                                  .put("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false")
                                  .put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps"))
                          .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(false)
                          .shouldDeleteMessages(false)
                          .simpleContent(true),
                  e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(props.getPollRate())))
            .transform(emailToUserTransformer)
            .handle(userMessageHandler)
            .get();
}
```

Comment: i had a problem where parts of a javax.mail.Multipart -object could not be retrieved, setSimpleContent(true) seems to have solved it!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem in *mail-attachments* project of:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration

I resolved it with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.19.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-bom</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

EDIT: It's ok also with version 5.1.3.RELEASE but it's necessary:
simple-content="true" in mail:inbound-channel-adapter